# Window minimize does not work

Tags: unity, 13.10

So after installing Gnome 3.10 on my Ubuntu 13.10 and playing around with it my Unity desktop is a bit bugged. When I try to minimize a window, nothing happens.

Now, when I press the windows key and alt, the window minimizes with a bit of graphical lag seen. But doing this multiple times will crash the whole DE pretty much.

Where could i start looking from for the cause of the problem?